# Appium inspector unable to locate integrated applePay screen

Tags: ios, appium, applepay

Appium inspector unable to locate any elements of integrated ApplePay screen of my iOS Test Application. The issue happens on iOS 11 with 1.7.1 appium.

The controller used to built the apple Pay is `PKPaymentAuthorizationController`.

The same action was tried out with iOS 10 and 1.6.5 appium, where I could locate elements.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you get an answer for your very specific issue here, but I can give an advice how to make it more specific and find help faster:

1. Check if it works for iOS 10 and Appium 1.7.1.
2. If it works then its iOS 11 limitation and you probably need to post issue to [WebDriverAgent](https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent) repo.
3. If it doesn't work, then its more likely Appium XCUITest regression issue. Report it [here](https://github.com/appium/appium)